# What is the meaning of twelve months for climate at Gale Crater, Mars?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, climate

I noticed that [Wikipedia lists the climate on Gale Crater per “month”](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Climate_of_Mars&oldid=776379487#Temperature):

[image: Climate on Mars, screenshot]
*Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Climate_of_Mars&oldid=776379487#Temperature)*.

None of the sources listed contain the information included in the table.  I find it particularly puzzling that the year in this table is divided into 12 months which thus should be an average 668.6/12=55.7 sols each.  Proposals for [timekeeping on Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars) may divide the year into 24 months, but simply counting the [668.6 sols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars) in analogy to day-of-year counting is, as far as I know, more common.

What does it mean to state that the average high temperature in Gale Crater in February is -18°C?  Does this have any meaning, or is this just an example flawed original research creeping into Wikipedia?

Answer (score 2):

The [Centro Astrobiologica](http://cab.inta-csic.es/rems/en/weather-report-mars-year-33-month-10/) site has temperature and other graphs divided into 360 degrees (=one Mars orbit).

[image: Pressure graph]

> Solar longitude is commonly referred to as Ls, this is the angular position of Mars relative to the Sun measured in degrees from the summer equinox (start of northern hemisphere Spring). The Ls year is divided into 360 fractions (degrees).

It's possible was misinterpreted into 360 days->one Earth year. So no original research, but flawed collation of data.